# Split A4 page in two, repeat header after half page height in ConteXt

Tags: context, printing, imposition

I don't really know what to search for, but I can't seem to find a way to split my A4 page contentwise. 
To avoid Problems with printer settings I want have two A5 Pages on one A4 Page in one step, so I don't have to combine two A5 Pages afterwards.

thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyword that you are looking for is **`imposition`** or **`arranging`**. See [the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition) or Section 3.6 of the [reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf).

The basic macro for imposition is `\setuparranging[...]`. Note that you need to run

```
context --arrange filename
```

to get the correct output.

To get two A5 portrait pages on a simple A4 page (as a page saving measure), you need to `2SIDE` option. Here is a minimal example illustrating its use.

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A4,landscape]
\setuparranging[2SIDE]

\setupheadertexts[Example of imposition]
\setuppagenumbering[location=bottom]

\showframe % To visualize the layout

\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth}
\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

To get two A5 landscape pages on a simple A4 page (as a page saving measure), you need to `2TOP` option. Here is a minimal example illustrating its use.

```
\setuppapersize[A5,landscape][A4]
\setuparranging[2TOP]

\setupheadertexts[Example of imposition]
\setuppagenumbering[location=bottom]

\showframe

\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]